# Easier line referencing

Tags: vim, plugins

I was wondering if anyone knows of a plugin to enable easier line determination.

I have issues quickly scanning to see what line I was to reference in commands such as `t` and `m`

See this screenshot:

[image]

If I wanted to quickly reference line 5 (I **do** have line numbers switched on, I just accidentally cut it out in this screenshot) I find I have to look rather hard to find the correct line number.

so: Is there a plugin which makes referencing lines less eye-straining?

Comment: Have you tried using relative line numbers instead instead of absolute? For example, `:-3t.` instead of `:5t.`. You might find this easier when you're working with lines near the cursor.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail *why* or *how* you find it hard to find the right line number? Is it to do with the colour? Is it because the line is deeply indented? etc. ...

Comment: @glts Because it is deeply indented

Answer (score 4):

I guess your problem is with those deeper indented lines. sometime it is not easy to "connect" the line number and the line text. If this is the case, you may try followings:

```
set listchars=tab:>-
```

(see `:h 'listchars'` for detail) this line will show the `<tab>` with certain chars. for example, following screenshot is a formatted maven pom.xml, with relative deeper indent lines. I think it would be ok to read the line numbers of them. E.g. the line 1180-1184.

I hope it helps.

[image]

**with plugin**

If the above doesn't help, e.g. you have spaces not `<tab>`, you could try a plugin: indentLine, with this you could set a variable `g:indentLine_char` with the char you like. e.g. `>` to show indent level clearly.

The link of the plugin: https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine

Comment: what if someone uses spaces for indentation instead of tabs?

Comment: @Walfie added a plugin

Answer (score 1):

`:move` and `:copy` are not limited to line numbers (absolute or relative) only, either as source or as target.

You can use search patterns too:

```
:m?foo
```

would move the current line just under the first line matching `foo` going upward,

```
:t/bar
```

would copy the current line just under the first line matching `bar` going downward,

```
:?foo?t/bar
```

would copy the first line matching `foo` above the current line to just below the first line matching `bar` going downward, and so on.

You can also use marks:

```
:'at'b
```

would copy the line marked `a` to below the line marked `b`,

```
:m''
```

would move the current line to just below the line you were before the last jump, and so on.